# Convert Prototype to jQuery when using ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

I have the following Prototype javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function go(qry) {
    new Ajax.Request('script.py?q=' + qry,
        {method: 'GET'}
    );
  }
</script>
```

Is there a way of making this work with jQuery? I'm not sure how to use the `jQuery.ajax()` method in the context of the original Prototype version.

I've also seen a `jQuery.get()` method, not too sure which I should be using.

I was wondering if something like the following would be along the right lines?

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  $.ajax({
function go(qry) {
url: 'doStuff.py?q=' + qry
    );
  });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function go(qry) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'script.py?q=' + qry,
    });
  }
</script>
```